# google cloud operation stuck at RUNNING unless I exit the script

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to import a csv data from google storage to a google cloud sql table, the operation status is stuck at RUNNING unless I exit the script

```
credentials_dict = {...}  # service account json
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    credentials_dict, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
)
authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)
payload={
"importContext":
{
    "fileType": "CSV",
    "uri": "gs://<path-to-csv>",
    "database": "<db-name>",
    "csvImportOptions":
    {
        "table": "<table-name>"
    }
}
}
response = authed_session.request('POST', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/<project-id>/instances/<cloude-sql-instance-id>/import',json=payload)
data = json.loads(response.text)
name = data["name"]
while response.status_code == 200 and  data["status"] != "DONE":
    sleep(5)
    response = authed_session.request(
    'GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/<project-id>/operations/' + name)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
```

Comment: After reviewing https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues#viewing_logs, update your question if you still need help

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start troubleshooting this is from [Diagnosing issues with Cloud SQL instances](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues).

I would start by viewing the [Cloud SQL instance operation logs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues#viewing_logs)

Comment: The problem was calling the import_csv_to_table code inside a with psycopg2 /conn.cursor() block to create the data table, conn.commit() fixed the issue.